# iOS project works in simulator but not on iPhone 5

Tags: ios-simulator, iphone-5, xcode-storyboard, stack-unwinding

I have finished my project in Xcode 6. Tested on simulator. Everything works fine. So installed app on my hardware. (iPhone 5 ) however looks like prepare for segue and unwind to segue methods does not get called. Due to this properties I set in these methods stays nil. And so app crashed. 
Please help.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to crack it. Problem was declaration of property in .h file for NSString. It was declared weak. Changing it to strong sorted my problem.